# Analog video capture (Hauppauge Live USB) Error - vidioc_qbuf: message too long

Tags: video, opencv, v4l

I know about [Hauppauge 610 Analog Video Capture Script or Command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700972/hauppauge-610-analog-video-capture-script-or-command) and [Script to Capture VHS Tapes Using the Hauppauge 610 USB-Live 2 Analog Video Digitizer and Video Capture Device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848713/script-to-capture-vhs-tapes-using-the-hauppauge-610-usb-live-2-analog-video-digi). I run their scripts and still get my error.

I have been trying to capture video from a Sony XC-ST50 camera using a coax-rca plug into a Hauppauge USB-Live2 on `18.04`.  I installed the drivers as they describe [here](https://github.com/b-rad-ndi/ubuntu-media-tree-kernel-builder).  I have tried opening this with `OpenCV` and `ffmpeg` with various commands using `v4l2` including `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0  -vf format=yuv420p -framerate 25  output.mp4`. Each time I get some variation on this error:

`[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x561552c8d820] ioctl(VIDIOC_QBUF): Message too long
/dev/video0: Message too long`